# Caching first PHP flush of multiple flushes

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache, flush, etag

in my web application, I am calling PHP\flush or ob_flush several times in order to show partial content to my users. Say I call flush three or four times.

If the first flush doesn't really change much between page loads, is there a way to cache this on the browser? I was looking into ETags and Cache-Control, but given that these are partial caches, are there any browser-side solutions that could come into play?

Comment: The short answer is “no”. Partial caches might be a thing at the “edge” under very specific contexts, but are not part of the normal HTTP protocol. The longer answer is that if you are concerned about partial DOM rendering you might want to look at server-side DOM-aware things which inevitably are JS-based things.

Comment: Instead, however, I’d recommend to look at rendering the “shell” and then lazily making AJAX/fetch calls for the content. This is a very common pattern that users tend to perceive as, if not “faster”, more performant.